# Empathy IM: interface unusable, not rendered adequately

Tags: release-loki, user-interface, thirdpartyapps

I cannot do anything in Empathy IM as the GUI looks like this:
[image: unusable Empathy GUI]

The add account window is not usable on Loki 0.4. Are there any solutions I can try out?

My question could be a duplicate of [this one](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/9252/empathy-irc-cant-create-account). I just wonder, if I can't do anything about this, is there a way to diagnose whether this is a elementary or an empathy IM problem, so I can report it to the right people?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it like this:

```
sudo apt-get install telepathy-* empathy empathy-skype
```

I found this solution here: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=98273

Comment: That worked for me too! But I had to import my accounts from pidgin. Only the import button was working. After an account was imported, everything seems to work as it should!